# Config generate javadoc in gradle

Tags: gradle, format, javadoc, document, generated-code

I'm using Gradle to coding and using default Generate document of sts to generate java doc. But document has trouble about library in function description.

[image]

**- Currently**, for all type it always display full lib: java.lang.String for String
**- Expect**, only display type and has reference to type: String for String

Answer (score 0):

If you use the standard JavaDoc doclet, the following whould help

```
javadoc.options.links 'https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/'
```

Comment: I add that to build gradle and refresh dependencies after that generate document but error still occurs.

Comment: I don't use android gradle, so may be it not affect

Comment: What error occurs? You did not say anything about an error. What should this have to do with Android?

Comment: My mean is the document. I still display String instead of java.lang.String. I fixed this cause. I download java api document, after that add api documentation path in "Select referenced archives and projects to which links should be generated" when genera document is ok